# Joining data from different Excel spreadsheets onto a fourth using a common identifier

Tags: join, csv, records

**Issue and Goal**

I have three csv files, the first one contains customer names and their unique customer numbers.  The second csv file contains addresses, telephone numbers, plus unique customer numbers.  The third contains order histories plus unique customer numbers.

I am trying to combine all three lists into a single Excel worksheet, with Customer names, addresses and order histories on the same line.

**Desired Output**

Customer #, Bob Brown, 100 Hill St, Los Angeles, CA 90006, 888-888-8888, Order History

Customer #, Tim Jones, 120 First St, San Diego, CA 91111, 888-888-8888, Order History

**What I've tried thus far**

I imported and copied each list into the same worksheet and used Vlookup to find the common identifiers.  While it worked to find items that have matches, I have to manually cut and paste items that don't have matches.  For instances, not all customers have order histories.

If someone knows of a way to automate this, that will be super!  I realize Access is probably the better tool for this but my experience with Access is zero, zip, zilch, nada, nothing, "the big donut!"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why not import them via phpmyadm in into a database, then use join to join them all and then use the libexcel from php to output it.

thats what i would do.

or in excel

place all values in 3 diff sheets, copy all unique customer numbers to sheet 4 and then use vlookup ifunction in excel to combine data

Comment: I can't use any software other than what is on my company PC.  What is this "ifunction" that you speak of?  Let me take a look.

Comment: Vertical search. it looks for value x in col a and returns b on the same row as the value was found. look it up in the excel help files how to use it.

Comment: OK, I see what you are talking about now, I was not familiar with the term "ifunction."  I did mention that I have tried vlookup in my first post.  The problem with vlookup is only items that have matching counterparts are identified.  For instance, customers with no order histories are not identified.  That is what I meant by having to manually cut and paste.  Sorry for the confusion.